# Getting type of derived class from base class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, reflection

I have the following situation:

```
class Base<T>
class Derived : Base<Derived>
```

I know it is a bad practice that the base class knows who is the child class. I want to implement a Singleton base class, and for this, the base class must know who is the derived class, so please don't comment on this bad practice.

Is there a way to get the derived class type?

Getting the type using reflection is obviously problematic, because reflection is kind of static, and you can't cover the case of multiple derived classes.

EDIT: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I  meant that I want to be able to inherit the base class without specifiying the generic argument. It is a little stupid to pass yourself to the base class

Comment: In your example you can reference T in the base class which will be the derived type.

Comment: _I want to be able to inherit the base class without specifiying the generic argument._  hmm, no, you can't do that. at least not with a statically typed language (mostly).

Comment: It is not possible with specifying generic argument because  you can not force derived class in curiously recursive template to pass correct class (itself) in C#...

Comment: there is absolutely no problem to use reflection... why are you deriving from a singleTone class? also Singletones are 99% of the time inappropriate and are a bad practice generally

Comment: It's (basically) impossible for a base class to be a singleton.  The derived type needs to have access to a constructor of the base type to ever create an instance, and if it can do that, then multiple instances of the base type can be created, making it no longer a singleton.

Comment: @AK_ I know singleton is quite bad, but I am writing kind of an infrastructure for applications that have logical modules that each do it's own work, and it doesn't make sense to create multiple instances of them.
Servy, I dont want to make the base class singleton. I have already implemented the base class with reflection of the generic type (which is the derived class) constructor.

Nevermind

Comment: The fact that right now it doesnt make sense to you doesnt mean it will not make sense in an actual use case. You should make something singletone only if it will crash and burn otherwise. And what  you are really looking for is probably some sort of 'factory' design pattern

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern#Classification_and_list

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are looking for, but code in base class knows its type when it is used as part of derived class:

```
class C1 
{
   public C1() { Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().Name);}
}
class C2: C1 {  }

new C2(); // writes C2 from C1's constructor.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `RuntimeType` of `T`, use `Type derivedType = typeof(T)` from within `Base<T>`